# Escape parenthesis in perl while logging output to file

Tags: perl, sh

I am logging the output of a cli which is the change set details to a log file using the following code:

This code works fine but when the change set details contains parenthesis i.e. () it is breaking and results in the below error.

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
sh: -c: line 0: `scm list changes 5313) ---$ ABC "Changed to Kill SNMP Agent upon stop( -r rtcuser >> WIassociatedtoComp.log'
```

My code is :

```
foreach $changeset(@cs_ids) {
        my $getWIs = "scm list changes $changeset -r rtcuser";
        `$getWIs >> WIassociatedtoComp.log`;
        }
```

What can be done to escape these parenthesis and log this entry to log successfully.

Comment: Try with quotes :         `"$getWIs" >> "WIassociatedtoComp.log"`;

Comment: This is still not working. The point is if string $getWIs contains parentheses it should be written as such to the log fil

Answer (score 1):

The output looks like the `$changeset` variable contains shell meta characters. Try to enclose that in single quotes:

```
foreach $changeset(@cs_ids) {
    my $getWIs = "scm list changes '$changeset' -r rtcuser";
    `$getWIs >> WIassociatedtoComp.log`;
}
```

Is the output still the same? Then please insert into the loop:

```
print "$getWIs\n";
```

Comment: The answer solves the described problem. If _It is still not working_, describe the new problem.